# Function changes all column data of DF to the same value and ignores that conditions are different for different rows. And .Apply() gives Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, apply

Please, give me an advice about how to .apply( ) in correct way to get correct result.

I have 2 Pandas dataframes with 'a','b','c' columns. And i want to change some 'c'-column data of the second dataframe df_2. It is needed to change df_2 'c'-data for those rows only where 'a' is equal to 1. Zero 0 in those 'c'-rows has to be changed to median value counted on those 'c'-rows of the first dataframe df_1 where 'a' is 1. I wrote a function to do it. It is applied to df_2 and uses df_1 data.

**The problem is:**

1. If function is applied like this: 'df_2['c'] = set_c(df_1, df_2)', all 'c'-column of df_2 gets new price, no matter is 'a' == 1 or not. It is incorrect.
2. If function is applied like this: 'df_2['c'] = df_2.apply(set_c(df_2, df_1))', error occures: 'AssertionError:' and no additional comments.

**Code is:**

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,1], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,100,9]}) # From C
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,50,6], 'c': [0,0,0]}) # To C

display('df_1', df_1)
display('df_2', df_2)

def set_c(df1, df2):
    
    mask = ( df1.loc[:, 'a'] == df2.loc[0, 'a'] )
    final_c = df1[mask]['c'].median()
    
    display("df2.loc[0, 'a']", df2.loc[0, 'a'])
    display('df1[mask]', df1[mask])
    print('final_c median', final_c)
    
    return final_c

df_2['c'] = set_c(df_1, df_2)

display(df_2)
```

df_2 and df_1 are global dataframes outside the function, df2 and df1 are dataframes inside the function used as function parameters.

My function shows all the process of its working. For variant 1 it shows such steps:

```
'df_1'
    a   b   c
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   100
2   1   6   9

'df_2'
    a   b   c
0   1   4   0
1   2   50  0
2   3   6   0

"df2.loc[0, 'a']" # 'a'=1 is a mask base for counting 'c'-median on df_1 data
1
 
'df1[mask]' # Rows of df_1 with 'a'=1 were found!
    a   b   c
0   1   4   7
2   1   6   9

final_c median 8.0 # It is median between 7 and 9 of df1

'df_2 result'
    a   b   c
0   1   4   8.0
1   2   50  8.0
2   3   6   8.0
```

Could you please show me how is it correct to apply this function for it to give such a result of df_2 with new 'c'=8.0 **in row [0], but in row[1] - 100 ('a'=2), in row[2] - 0 (no 'a'=3 in df_1):

```
'df_2 result'
    a   b   c
0   1   4   8.0
1   2   50  100.0
2   3   6   0.0
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `df1[mask]['c']` - why didn't you use `df1.loc[mask,'c']`?

Comment: `'c'=8.0 in row [0] only` -- `df_2.loc[0,'c'] = set_c(df_1, df_2)`??

Comment: WWII, thank You for Your response. I mean that in this dataframes it would be row [0] with 8.0 exactly because df_1 has two rows with 'a'=1 ('c' = 7 and 9). I made a small mistake and after Your answer I changed in 'c'[1] in df_1 to 100. Now in the row[1] of df_1 and df_2 zero is changed to 100, cause 'a'[1]=2 in df_1 and df_2 gives 'c'[1] = 100. In row[2] of df_2 we get the same 0, cause there is no 'a'=3 in df_1. In common for any different 'a' wich would be found in df_2 and df_1 new median values have to be counted. Thank you. You helped me to make my question better and more clear! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your meaning correctly, I suggest using the apply method with axis=1 and transferring to the function the index row, then using it as an index for the loc.

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 100, 9]})  # From C
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 50, 6], 'c': [0, 0, 0]})  # To C


def set_c(df1, df2, i):
    mask = (df1.loc[:, 'a'] == df2.loc[i, 'a'])
    final_c = df1[mask]['c'].median()

    return final_c


df_2['c'] = df_1.apply(lambda x: set_c(df_1, df_2, x.name), axis=1).fillna(0)
print(df_2)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   a   b      c
0  1   4    8.0
1  2  50  100.0
2  3   6    0.0
```

Comment: Dear Ze'ev Ben-Tsvi, thank You very much, You helped me a lot. May I ask You a pair of additional qiestions? 1) Am I right that if df_1 has 100 rows and df_2 has 50 rows, function will be applied 100 times if we use 'df_1.apply(... x.name...)' and 50 times if we use 'df_2.apply(... x.name...)'? 2) Function above needs i. But how does this simple example works without i?    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [0,0,0]})    def c_sum(a, b):    return df[a]+df[b]    df['c'] = c_sum('a','b')    display(df)  - What is the principal difference between this and Your example? Thank you!

Comment: @newnewer Thanks for your kind words, I'm not an expert (yet) but I'll try my best to answer your questions. 1) It is true that applying a dataframe with a length of 100 rows will iterate through 100 rows. 2) It is not necessary to use i, I used it to not change much of your code, I could replace x.name (the row index) with x['c'] the value of 'c' at the given row (x is the row from iterating through df_1). Your example function returns a series that will fit the destination, the apply method is iterating through the given series, builds from each iteration function call the series returned.